# ThreadLocal instance getting null at some cases

Tags: java, thread-local

Getting ThreadLocal instance as null. Using the following code, I had created new ThreadLocal instance.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> inputSdfLocal = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>()
    {
        protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
        {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        };
    };
```

Now I am calling ThreadLocal (inputSdfLocal) instance as inputSdfLocal.get().

```
SimpleDateFormat inputSdf = inputSdfLocal.get();
```

At this point some time, I am getting ThreadLocal ->inputSdfLocal instance as null. Will anyone please explain, why  ThreadLocal instance getting null.

Comment: Very interesting. From where are you calling the `inputSdfLocal.get()` ? Did you find any pattern, when does it occur? Or it is random on every run?

Comment: It is random and calling in same class. I had called ThreadLocal instance many times (More than 10 times).At some point, I am getting null for TheadLocal instance and after that always I am getting null. Then I will terminate my jboss instance and start a new Jboss instance means, I able to get ThreadLocal instance for further process.

Comment: Could you check the jboss logs for any errors/exceptions? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Can you look through your code and see if you ever call `inputSdfLocal.set` or `inputSdfLocal.remove`?

Comment: @durron597 - Thanks for your response. I am using inputSdfLocal.get() only to get the required date format. I had never used inputSdfLocal.remove() and set() in my code.

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates this issue? It should not be possible for `inputSdfLocal.get()` to trigger an NPE with the code snippet you've provided, which likely means either a) the issue is somewhere else, not `inputSdfLocal` or b) the provided snippet doesn't actually reflect the code that's triggering this error. If you can share an MCVE we can replicate the issue and help diagnose it.